# SOAP header is not being set

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to send authentication header in SOAP but it's not working and keep showing error like 'Invalid authentication info'.

```
$options=array(
'senderCity'=>'Atlanta',
'senderState'=>'GA',
'senderZip'=>'30005',
'senderCountryCode'=>'USA',
'receiverCity'=>'Atlanta',
'receiverState'=>'GA',
'receiverZip'=>'30005',
'receiverCountryCode'=>'USA'
            );

$headerbody = array(
        'loginId'=>'xxxxxxxx',
        'password'=>'xxxxxxxx',
        'licenseKey'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'accountNumber'=>'xxxxxxxxxx');

$soap_client = new SoapClient('http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/services/SpeedFreightShipment?wsdl');

$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/', 'AuthenticationToken', $headerbody, false);
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header)); 

$result = $soap_client->__call('quoteSpeedFreightShipment',$options);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "<pre>";
```

Can any one help me to resolve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your namespace,

```
$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.wwexship.com', 'AuthenticationToken', $headerbody, false);
```

Comment: Corrected the namespace but still same authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got the solution so posting it herewith .... atleast save this solution and send it to the affected users so that they can use it

### Steps to test

1. Create a PHP page
2. Copy paste below code
3. Change the user, pwd, acct# and key in the soap_request variable text...
4. Code

========================

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/services/SpeedFreightShipment";

$soap_request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wwex="http://www.wwexship.com">    <soapenv:Header>       <wwex:AuthenticationToken>          <wwex:loginId>LOGIN_ID</wwex:loginId>          <wwex:password>PASSWPRD</wwex:password>          <wwex:licenseKey>LIC_KEY</wwex:licenseKey>          <wwex:accountNumber>ACCT_NUMB</wwex:accountNumber>       </wwex:AuthenticationToken>    </soapenv:Header>    <soapenv:Body>       <wwex:quoteSpeedFreightShipment>          <wwex:freightShipmentQuoteRequest>               <wwex:insuranceDetail xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>                <wwex:senderState>AZ</wwex:senderState>             <wwex:senderZip>85027</wwex:senderZip>              <wwex:senderCountryCode>USA</wwex:senderCountryCode>                <wwex:receiverState>NY</wwex:receiverState>             <wwex:receiverZip>11428</wwex:receiverZip>                  <wwex:receiverCountryCode>USA</wwex:receiverCountryCode>                             <wwex:commdityDetails>                <wwex:is11FeetShipment>N</wwex:is11FeetShipment>                <wwex:handlingUnitDetails>                   <wwex:wsHandlingUnit>                      <wwex:typeOfHandlingUnit>Box</wwex:typeOfHandlingUnit>                      <wwex:numberOfHandlingUnit>1</wwex:numberOfHandlingUnit>                                           <wwex:lineItemDetails>                         <wwex:wsLineItem>                            <wwex:lineItemHazmatInfo xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/><wwex:lineItemClass>50</wwex:lineItemClass>                            <wwex:lineItemWeight>1</wwex:lineItemWeight>                            <wwex:lineItemDescription>Diamond Box</wwex:lineItemDescription>                            <wwex:lineItemPieceType>Pallet</wwex:lineItemPieceType>                            <wwex:piecesOfLineItem>1</wwex:piecesOfLineItem>                         </wwex:wsLineItem>                      </wwex:lineItemDetails>                   </wwex:wsHandlingUnit>                </wwex:handlingUnitDetails>             </wwex:commdityDetails>          </wwex:freightShipmentQuoteRequest>       </wwex:quoteSpeedFreightShipment>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>';

$header = array(
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"SOAPAction: \"http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/services/SpeedFreightShipment\"",
"Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
);

$soap_do = curl_init();

curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap_request);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);

echo "<pre>".$result."<pre>";
?>
```

===================================

For further help please get back @

http://www.linkedin.com/in/dramilmdodeja

Dramil Dodeja